# how to set validation textfield to the package?

Tags: flutter, dart, credit-card

I'm using [this](https://github.com/simformsolutions/flutter_credit_card) package in my application and Iwant to check if these fields are empty or not to navigate to the next page 
how can I verify these test fields?

[image]

Comment: Did you try anything yet ? Do you face any error while implementing the required ?

Comment: I solve it by copying the code of the package and change it as I need

Comment: That's fine. What is expected at StackOverlow is that you put the code snippet and ask a precise question as in what is going wrong in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)so that somebody can help you out. Please also see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: thank you for sharing that I'll check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package provide a callback onCreditCardModelChange, you can add your check logical there. 
In demo picture you can see print message

```
void onCreditCardModelChange(CreditCardModel creditCardModel) {
    setState(() {
      cardNumber = creditCardModel.cardNumber;
      expiryDate = creditCardModel.expiryDate;
      cardHolderName = creditCardModel.cardHolderName;
      cvvCode = creditCardModel.cvvCode;
      isCvvFocused = creditCardModel.isCvvFocused;
    });

    if(cardNumber.isNotEmpty && expiryDate.isNotEmpty && cardHolderName.isNotEmpty && cvvCode.isNotEmpty ) {
      print("add check logical or directly  navigate to next page");
    }
  }
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_credit_card/credit_card_form.dart';
import 'package:flutter_credit_card/credit_card_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_credit_card/flutter_credit_card.dart';

void main() => runApp(MySample());

class MySample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MySampleState();
  }
}

class MySampleState extends State<MySample> {
  String cardNumber = '';
  String expiryDate = '';
  String cardHolderName = '';
  String cvvCode = '';
  bool isCvvFocused = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Credit Card View Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              CreditCardWidget(
                cardNumber: cardNumber,
                expiryDate: expiryDate,
                cardHolderName: cardHolderName,
                cvvCode: cvvCode,
                showBackView: isCvvFocused,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: CreditCardForm(
                    themeColor: Colors.red,
                    onCreditCardModelChange: onCreditCardModelChange,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onCreditCardModelChange(CreditCardModel creditCardModel) {
    setState(() {
      cardNumber = creditCardModel.cardNumber;
      expiryDate = creditCardModel.expiryDate;
      cardHolderName = creditCardModel.cardHolderName;
      cvvCode = creditCardModel.cvvCode;
      isCvvFocused = creditCardModel.isCvvFocused;
    });

    if(cardNumber.isNotEmpty && expiryDate.isNotEmpty && cardHolderName.isNotEmpty && cvvCode.isNotEmpty ) {
      print("add check logical or directly  navigate to next page");
    }
  }
}
```

[image]